# UNet Client Data Error: MessageToLong

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm sending a number of basic network messages from the server via NetworkServer.SendToAll as per [the manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html). Once I get to a certain throughput rate for these, the client starts erroring out with `MessageToLong` (sic) in `UNetStaticUpdate`. This is not an issue of (as one would think) the messages being too long, as they change only in number, not size.

I'm guessing there's some buffering mechanism going on behind the scenes that is failing to keep up?